is it possible to export latex file to read be read from InDesign?
I need that a file made by LaTeX should be opened by Acrobat InDesign. Is it possible?
I've also Thought to pass Throught Pandoc.
on whitch format can I export latex and whitch canimport in Indesign?
Or, there is nothing to share between them?
Thank you
Renato

Do you want to see the image, or manipulate its data! What kind of content do you have in mind? Can you add examples to your question?

I have a magazine (text and images) made by latex, I need that this file, could be opened an managed by some people that use InDesign.

it would anyway be a one-way transformation if you manage to convert the latex generated pdf to something indesign can handle, any changes made there would not be possible to push back to the tex source.

How many relevant pages does the magazine have, roughly? In a professional context we often made the decision to redo it in the other tool: more often than not this was faster than converting or/and removing errors. Images will certainly be available as screenshot from the pdf, at least.
